Dynamic recipient in Freeform plugin Pro
I'm trying to set up a process with Freeform and I haven't managed to do it. I'd like your input on feasibility. To prevent spamming, I don't want content editors to add email addresses in plain text in the pages content, and I also don't want to have to deal with email obfuscation.
Here's my plan:

Email type entry, with name and email address of recipient.
One generic form: User email and comments/question fields.
Content editor would add links to the form page with the email entry id as parameter.
In the form configuration, the recipient would be dynamic, based on the id passed in parameter.

Thanks,
